# How to Notify Deadlocks in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres databases. Can anyone suggest how to notify if there is deadlock happening in postgres. How to set email alerts for this deadlocks .

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In most circumstances, Postgres should detect deadlocks and abort one of the transactions automatically.

Comment: I think the question is intended to be "when a deadlock abort occurs, how can I be notified?". In which case: use a log watching tool.

Comment: we need email notification alert for this. please share if u have any process

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Postgres logs the deadlock information in its log files under /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log directory. You can create a script that read the log files and grep the word 'deadlock' and notify through email. Schedule a cron job to run the script frequently in a day. Of course, the limitation is that you may not get emails at the moment deadlock occurs, but still could be helpful.

Thanks